# How should one cross the IJ river with a bike?

Tags: amsterdam

The IJ river flows through Amsterdam. Well, actually, it flows North of historical Amsterdam, but these days there's a Northern borough.

[image]

I've never been north of the river before, and I'm going there soon. I thought I'd take my bike, but they're not very amphibian, and it occurred to me I don't know whether I can safely cross anywhere...

- OpenStreetMap shows a [path](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/52.38131/4.90051&layers=CND) but there doesn't seem to be a bridge there, nor a tunnel
- There's the IJtunnel, but I don't know whether I can cycle through it, nor whether it's a good idea with the car smog
- There are ferries, but I don't know whether these allow bikes and whether it's too pricey to be worth it.

What are my options?

(Yes I know I can just cycle around the bank and see, or also ask around, I'd just rather plan ahead.)

Comment: The IJ tunnel is illegal for pedestrians, cyclists and mopeds (source: lived in A'dam for years).

Comment: Pedantry: it's "IJ", not "Ij". The letter IJ is a [digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IJ_%28digraph%29).

Comment: @Evert: Thanks, I know the pronounciation is joint and special, but I didn't realize it was a digraph.

Comment: An other pedant remark. The IJ is the left overs of a lake, not a river. And near Centraal Station is changed into the Noord Zee kanaal. The lake and canal allow river water from the river Amstel out to the sea, but neither is a river.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The route that you highlighted on the map is the ferry route. It operates 24/7. It allows bikes and it is completely free.

[More info](http://www.iamsterdam.com/en/visiting/plan-your-trip/getting-around/public-transport/ferry) about ferries in Amsterdam.

There is also [bridge](https://www.google.nl/maps/dir/Schellingwoude/Insulindeweg+1002,+1095+DH+Amsterdam/@52.3743817,4.9508655,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c60927b7a9e821:0xf70377572b647797!2m2!1d4.9617484!2d52.3832269!1m5!1m1!1s0x47c6093f6627639d:0x726e62c79b0f9392!2m2!1d4.9520971!2d52.3649652!3e1?hl=en) on the east of Amsterdam.

And there are plans to build bike tunnel close to IJ tunnel.

Comment: source for the bike tunnel plans? (so we can follow its evolution and may be add a prospective opening date)

Comment: http://www.except.nl/nl/projects/424-amsterdam-bike-tunnel-ijfietstunnel

Comment: @njzk2, you have nice blog, are you in NL?

Comment: Thank you for the compliment. I am not in NL, no (not even in Europe).

Comment: The ferry ride takes, oh, 3-4 minutes, but the wait can be as much as 11 or 12 minutes. But, well, it gets you there. GVB rulez.

Answer (score 8):

Eugen Martynov's answer discusses what IS possible. My answer will discuss the IJ tunnel, which he didn't mention.

From what I can tell on Google Street View, the IJ tunnel is a poorly-lit tunnel with 2 lanes in both directions and no indications for cyclists or pedestrians. In addition, the tunnel is part of the s116, a major motorway through the heart of Amsterdam with, again, no cyclist or pedestrian amenities. The s116 is heavy in traffic and mostly inaccessible by anything besides motor vehicles. Driving there with you bike is <strike>likely</strike> illegal, most likely extremely dangerous and definitely a bad idea.

---

as Evert mentioned in a comment, **the IJ tunnel is off-limits** for pedestrians and cyclers.

Answer (score -1):

Yah, from my time in Amsterdam one of my favourite days out was to hop on the ferry behind centraal station and then head north. Superb riding, recommend Marken as a suitable destination. Ferry is free and quick. Or it was 8 years ago.

Comment: Ferries are still free and fast for bikes. And due to laws and traditions, likely to be so for a long time to come. When the metro runs under the IJ, it is not free to travel on, the city is bound to provide free transport for walking and cycling. (I am living near, on the other end of the canal starting in the IJ.)